# How to pass path parameter in new File() constructor in Java in Unix System

Tags: java

I am trying to create an XML file with the below Code

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File("/var/log/idm/vendavo   /vendavo.xml"));
transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
```

But I am getting Exception FileNotFoundException.

And when I am trying to read a properties file with

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("/var/log/idm/vendavo/vendavo.properties");
```

It is working.
My system in Unix system.

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"/var/log/idm/vendavo   /vendavo.xml"`...are the spaces a mistake?  Do you have permisson to write to the directory/file?

Comment: Is the file vendavo.xml already created in /var/log/idm/vendavo/ when above mentioned code runs?

Comment: Yes the spaces are placed during posting the question by mistake.And yes I have permission to write to the directory file.

Comment: And what about the file? First code sample shows "vendavo.xml", second code has "vendavo.properties"? Also a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

**FileReader** is used for reading the contents of a file. The file must exist and permissions must be set to allow you to read the file. This class does not do anything else.

**File** can be used to test those permissions with the File.isFile() and File.canRead() to test to make sure the path is a valid file and you have permissions to read it respectively.

It mostly looks like an issue with permission, try calling canRead()

```
File f = new File(path);
System.out.println(f.canRead());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the [FileNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html) because the file `/var/log/idm/vendavo/vendavo.xml` is not present in the directory.

```
StreamResult result=new StreamResult(File f)
```

Above constructors expects a non null file reference ,I'd suggest you to use following piece of code.

```
try(FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("/var/log/idm/vendavo/vendavo.xml")))
{
   TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
   Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
   DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
   StreamResult result=new StreamResult(fout);
   transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
}
```